# How to print horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script that is supposed to print an answer to a specific input horizontally.

For example if the input is:

```
TTACTGGCAT
```

It should print:

```
TTACTGGCAT
AATGACCGTA
```

My code:

```
x = 0
n = input("Insert DNA seqence: ")
print(n.upper())
while x < len(n):
  if 'T' in n[x]:
    print('A')
  if 'G' in n[x]:
    print('C')
  if 'C' in n[x]:
    print('G')
  if 'A' in n[x]:
    print('T')
  x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do something like this:

```
nucl_dict = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}

n = input("Insert DNA seqence: ").upper()
print(n)
print(''.join(nucl_dict.get(nucl, nucl) for nucl in n))
```

`nucl_dict` defines which nucleotides are complementary.

This joins the characters for the corresponding nucleotides into a string and prints the result.

If the character is not a valid nucleotide, the character is simply added without a change to the complementary string. `get` tries to find the value given the first argument as a key (in this case each character in `n`) and if the key does not exist uses the second argument (in this case the same character).

Answer (score 0):

You should concat everything in a string and after the loops end print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end` parameter like `print(some_var, end='')` to not print ending newline after each call. In your loop you would want to print new line, so just run without the `end` parameter there. See [print documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print).